# Problema com chamada de EJB remoto com Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, ejb

estou tendo um problema com uma chamada RMI onde eu chamo um ejb remoto a partir de um jar. Ao debugar recebo o seguinte erro:

**"Failed to locate remote EJB [cell/persistent/ejb/br/com/X/XX/XXX/model/pagamento/ejb/XXXXSessionFacadeHome]"**

O mapeamento da classe está da seguinte forma pelo appcontext(estou usando spring), aparentemente o caminho da home do ejb está correto.

```
    <jee:remote-slsb id="XXXXSessionFacade" 
          business-interface="br.com.X.XX.XXX.model.pagamento.ejb.XXXXSessionFacade" 
          home-interface="br.com.X.XX.XXX.model.pagamento.ejb.XXXXSessionFacadeHome"
          cache-home="true" 
          lookup-home-on-startup="false" 
          jndi-name="cell/persistent/ejb/br/com/X/XX/XXX/model/pagamento/ejb/XXXXSessionFacadeHome"
          resource-ref="false">
    </jee:remote-slsb>
```

O jar também está no build path e declarado no servidor de aplicações.

Answer (score 1):

A aplicação na minha máquina está usando o tomcat 7 e ele não implementa a especificação Java EE, por isso não estava conseguindo rodar os EJBs. Mudar o servidor de aplicação provavelmente resolve o problema, a configuração que eu estou usando é para o WebSphere.